# When ordered by date, number each group of codes (with nulls and repeat codes)

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I've got a set of data as below - it is ordered by EmpID and EffDate. Note: This is a sample data set for one EmpID but there will be multiple EmpID's.

I'm trying to write SQL (for SQL Server 2008) to return the value in the Grp column. Eg when sorted by EffDate, number each group of PosCode's, until the PosCode changes. I don't mind if the Grp value is not consecutive (1,2,3,4 etc), it can be (2,5,7,8 etc) as long as they are grouped by a unique Grp number.

```
EmpID   EffDate     PosCode EndDate     Grp
1360    2013-10-05  NULL    NULL        1
1360    2014-08-04  NULL    NULL        1
1360    2015-03-16  P504    2015-04-05  2
1360    2016-01-04  P504    2016-01-15  2
1360    2016-08-01  NULL    NULL        3
1360    2017-01-30  NULL    NULL        3
1360    2017-02-13  NULL    NULL        3
1360    2018-03-29  P503    2018-07-02  4
1360    2018-05-10  P503    2018-07-02  4
1360    2018-07-02  P503    2018-11-23  4
1360    2018-11-24  P504    2018-12-23  5
```

This is the closest I can get, but all of the null values are grouped together when I need them broken into 2 different groups

```
select 
    EmpID, EffDate, PosCode, EndDate
    ,row_number() over (order by EffDate) 
        - row_number() over (partition by PosCode order by EffDate) as grp
from #p
order by 1, 2


EmpID   EffDate     PosCode EndDate     Grp
1360    2013-10-05  NULL    NULL        0
1360    2014-08-04  NULL    NULL        0
1360    2015-03-16  P504    2015-04-05  2
1360    2016-01-04  P504    2016-01-15  2
1360    2016-08-01  NULL    NULL        2
1360    2017-01-30  NULL    NULL        2
1360    2017-02-13  NULL    NULL        2
1360    2018-03-29  P503    2018-07-02  7
1360    2018-05-10  P503    2018-07-02  7
1360    2018-07-02  P503    2018-11-23  7
1360    2018-11-24  P504    2018-12-23  8
```

I'm thinking I may need to use APPLY to determine when the PosCode changes. I've tried a few things but I just can't get it working.

Thanks!

ETA: Using Gordon's code (I added ORDER BY 1,2), I still have the problem of the 2nd group having 5 members, when a new group should start when the NULLs start

```
EmpID   EffDate     PosCode EndDate     seqnum_p    seqnum_ep   grp
1360    2013-10-05  NULL    NULL        1   1   1
1360    2014-08-04  NULL    NULL        2   2   1
1360    2015-03-16  P504    2015-04-05  3   1   2
1360    2016-01-04  P504    2016-01-15  4   2   2
1360    2016-08-01  NULL    NULL        5   3   2
1360    2017-01-30  NULL    NULL        6   4   2
1360    2017-02-13  NULL    NULL        7   5   2
1360    2018-03-29  P503    2018-07-02  8   1   3
1360    2018-05-10  P503    2018-07-02  9   2   3
1360    2018-07-02  P503    2018-11-23  10  3   3
1360    2018-11-24  P504    2018-12-23  11  3   4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a "gaps-and-islands" problem.  In SQL Server 2008, you can approach it with a difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by empid order by min_id) as grp
from (select t.*,
             min(id) over (partition by empid, poscode, seqnum_p - seqnum_ep) as min_id
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by empid order by effdate) as seqnum_p,
                   row_number() over (partition by empid, poscode order by effdate) as seqnum_ep
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

It is a bit tricky to explain how this works.  My suggestion is to run the subquery and stare at the results from the row number functions.  You'll see how the difference is constant for the groups that you want to identify.

Comment: thanks for your quick response! It's not quite providing the Grps I need. I'll post the results

Comment: @jacy . . . I knew it was missing something.

Comment: in the 4th row, I replaced min(id) with min(seqnum_p) as id was causing an invalid column name. It gives the desired results!! thanks so much!